# INotifyPropertyChanged issue with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, inotifypropertychanged

See my CustomView window below

[image]

When I select project from the combobox, the client associated with that project should automatically displayed there.

In Combobox's selection changed event, I did so far

```
private string client 
{
 get
 {
 return ClientText.Text; 
 }
 set
 {
 ClientText.Text = value;
 }
}

 public Harvest_Project projectClass
    {
        set
        {
            ProjectText.Text = value.ToString();
            Harvest_Project proj = (Harvest_Project)ProjectText.Text; // shows error here. casting is not possible. What can I do here?
            this.client = Globals._globalController.harvestManager.getClientEntriesThroughId(proj._client_id)._name;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("client"));
        }
    }

public int project 
{
 get
 {
 return int.Parse(ProjectText.Text); 
 }
 set
 {
 ProjectText.Text = value.ToString(); 
 }
}

private void ProjectComboBoxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ComboBoxItem)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
        }
    }
```

In xaml I used binding like this,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProjectText" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectComboBoxChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0" Width="66"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler `ProjectComboBoxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`, sender is of type `ComboBox` and not `ComboBoxItem`, hence your `if` statement is always false.

`e.AddedItems[0]` will give you your desired `ComboBoxItem`. Make sure you check the count first.

Also, if all you want to do is to set the `Text`, you don't need to have the `client` property.

Answer (score 0):

"client" is a property, it should be public.
Then PropertyChanged should be raised in the setter, so anytime you change client, the UI will know.

About the combo, SelectedItem should bind to a property, not a method. The property could be "client", but another property could be clearer.

In the setter of this property, you'll have the liberty to fix the new value of the "client" property.

And last, since you are using a binding for selectedItem, I see no reason to use the event selectionChanged. Use binding or event, not both.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Please see edits. Suggest what can I do where the error is shown?